# Theorem of the dual isogeny in SIDH Zk proof

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, isogeny

In the proof of soundness for the SIDH ZK proof protocol (section 6.2 in [DJP11](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/506.pdf)) the authors refer to the "Theorem of the dual isogeny". What do they mean by this?

In particular, I don't understand why it easy to compute $\hat{\psi}$ when using Charles as a black box but not otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem of the dual isogeny states that for every isogeny $ψ:E→E'$ of degree n there exists an associated isogeny $\hat{ψ}:E'→E$ of the same degree such that $ψ∘\hat{ψ}$ and $\hat{ψ}∘ψ$ are equal to multiplication by $n$ on the respective curves. See Silverman, The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, Chapter III.

On top of that, there are efficient algorithms to compute $\hat{ψ}$ given $ψ$, and vice-versa. See, e.g., https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/499. This has nothing to do with using Charles as a black box.

Comment: My confusion stems from the fact that if it is easy to compute $\hat{\psi}$ given $\psi$, then this is also easy for Vic, and using the fact that $\langle \hat{\psi}(R) \rangle$ is the kernel of the secret isogeny $\phi: E \to E/S$, Vic would then be in possession of the secret key S.

Comment: $\hat{\psi}(R)$ is undefined, because $R \in E$, but the domain of $\hat{\psi}$ is $E'$, and $E' \neq E$.

Comment: That's why I don't understand the proof in DJP11, where it is said that $\langle \hat{\psi}(R) \rangle$ is the kernel of $\phi$ . In [YAJJS17](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/186), one computes $\hat{\psi}(\psi(S))$ to recover $S$, which makes sense to me

Comment: The confusion appears to stem from an unfortunate clash of notation. In diagram 6.1, $R$ generates the kernel of $ψ$. But, in the sentence you are quoting, it is said "Let $R$ be a generator of the kernel of $ϕ'$"; Using a different letter there would have been less confusing.